# Ruby compass - cannot load such file -- compass/core (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rbenv, compass

I'm trying to install and work around compass gem and the commands I used while installing this are -

```
gem install sass
gem install compass
```

Now I can see the version of sass with the command -

```
sass --version
```

But when I do -

```
compass --version
```

The messsage i get is -

```
/home/name/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- compass/core (LoadError)
from /home/name/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/name/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/name/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:13:in `each'
from /home/name/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/name/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/name/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/name/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/name/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
from /home/name/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:19:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/name/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/compass:22:in `load'
from /home/name/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/compass:22:in `<main>'
```

I've tried searching on google and went through whole lot of github issues and stackoverflow questions regarding compass, but any of those didn't help.

How should i resolve this issue?

**Update:-**
I was asked to include the o/p of following command here -

```
gem list -d | grep compass -A 4
```

**O/p:-**

```
    compass (1.0.3)
    Authors: Chris Eppstein, Scott Davis, Eric M. Suzanne, Brandon
    Mathis, Nico Hagenburger
    Homepage: http://compass-style.org
    Installed at: /home/name/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0

    A Real Stylesheet Framework

compass-core (1.0.3)
    Authors: Chris Eppstein, Scott Davis, Eric M. Suzanne, Brandon
    Mathis
    Homepage: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/
    License: MIT
    Installed at: /home/name/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0

    The Compass core stylesheet library
--
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
    Author: Chris Eppstein
    Homepage:
    https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/tree/master/import-once
    License: MIT
    Installed at: /home/name/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0

    Speed up your Sass compilation by making @import only import each
```

Comment: Please add the output of: `gem list -d | grep compass -A 4` to the question.

Comment: @Casper added the output.

Comment: Did you try it with Ruby 2.2 instead? Compass hasn't been maintained for a very long time and is no longer actively developed. It could be a Ruby 2.3 issue, so maybe try to downgrade? I have Ruby 2.2 and on this machine it works. Did not try it with 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby compass is no longer supported. Best get off. But I ran into the same issue, only one one VM, a linux machine with ruby 2.6.2p47 & gem 3.0.3, until finally I saw that gem install compass was not getting compass-core. Whereas on other versions it was getting it. Solution - do it explicitly:

```
gem install compass-core
```

Anyway - it worked for me and I hope it helps other stragglers!